# How do I preview a procedural texture to animate in BI?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to apply "distorted noise" texture to a material, to simulate moving white noise on an animation sequence (blender internal).

If I click "Render" in 3d viewport shading, I can see the material.  Any other option in 3d viewport (texture, material) gives me a cube with a solid color.  I really can't rely on my own imagination to predict how textures and images render since there are so many variables in blender.

The ultimate problem: I go to create an animation sequence - I have to wait about 2 hours to render, just to check the size, pitch, placement of the animated texture (or ANY texture) on the object in the scene.

Is it possible to edit objects with textures in a preview mode using blender-internal?  All my frustrated search results pin me back to "use cycles render"; which I am not interested in, since it takes overnight for me to render 2 minutes in cycles.